# Graph API - how to move email to sub folder in Inbox

Tags: php, graphql

Hi im try to move email from inbox to inbox/processed folder. i have written bellow code but it doesn't work

```
$dataar = array("destinationId" => "Inbox/processed");
$postdata = json_encode($dataar);
$chmove = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($chmove, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $urlsendgetattidmove,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postdata,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                 'Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token.''
               ),
  ));
$responsemove = curl_exec($chmove);
curl_close($chmove);
```

but if i put folder outside inbox then it works

```
 $dataar = array("destinationId" => "Archive");
```

Comment: What is the API? Are you using IMAP?

Comment: Microsoft  Graph API

Comment: Don't unlock queries one by one. Share the API doc link. What is the error message you get etc?

Answer (score 0):

i was able to do it by providing the folder id instead of name

```
  $dataar = array("destinationId" => 
  "J5RI79oYT8ILx0AQB2ou16VKQgQbgSOmYTxqIIAAdL44EXAAA=");
```